# App Store rejection - No icon on Game Center

Tags: ios, app-store, game-center, appstore-approval

After two weeks of waiting for my update on my game for iOS, I got it rejected with the following reason:

> We found that your app exhibited a bug, when reviewed on iPhone 4 and iPad
>       (3rd Generation) running iOS 5.1.1, on both Wi-Fi and cellular networks,
>       which is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.
>
> We found that when we launch the Game Center app and view your app that your
>       app icon does not load.

The update was to fix that I have missed to select to submit the leaderboards in my first release. So this new update was more or less the same version, but with the leaderboards and achievements selected in.

When I use the app in debug with sandbox account it works just fine. Any thoughts?

This is how I setup my leaderboards before submitting (which I forgot in the first version).

[image: Screenshot]

Icon and scores fully visible:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Nope, not that I can see

Comment: Alright just checking, does the image they're referring to display properly for you?

Comment: It's a screenshot showing how I setup my leaderboards before submitting (which I forgot in the first version). Does it not show for you?

Comment: I can see the screenshot, but in your quote from Apple "your app icon does not load." and I don't see anything in the screenshot that verifies that the icon is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps not an answer but this is how I solved it..

I just re-submitted it, saying in the review notes that it works well on a iPad 3rd gen device with a sandbox account and that the icon is fully visible. It got accepted and now works...

Answer (score 0):

Just reenable game center to your app